# MVC Application using ADFS 3.0 and ARR URL Rewrite getting incorrectly redirected after authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, owin, ws-federation, arr, adfs3.0

I have pretty much the same problem as mentioned in this question
[SSO ADFS redirection issue with reverse proxy with ARR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43433352/sso-adfs-redirection-issue-with-reverse-proxy-with-arr). However, I have tried the solution without success. The 302 from ADFS still goes to the private site instead of public.

I have also tried using **wreply** to explicitly define the public endpoint. I checked using browser Debug Tool and I can see that the ADFS request has the correct wreply value, however, redirection from ADFS is ignoring this.

I have verified the RP identifier in ADFS and it is correct.

Everything works fine in local environment when I host both the proxy and application in a single server and use the same ADFS endpoint for SSO.

The redirection from ADFS also works fine when I use idpinitiated sigon to login to the application.

Where could I be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

ARR changes the base URL after authentication happens. You need to restore the ADFS Base URL. I made it working using below ARR Rules.

You can use ADFS Rule mentioned in below rule set

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="ApplicationRule" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^dnApplication/?(.*)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="https://application.cloud.azurewebsites.net/dnApplication/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
<rule name="AdfsRule" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^.*adfs/?(.*)" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://gfs.private.companyName.com/adfs/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>
</rules>
      <outboundRules>
        <rule name="RedirectToHomeDNS" preCondition="3xx Redirect">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_LOCATION" pattern="^https://application-dv1.azurewebsites.net/" />
          <action type="Rewrite" value="{HTTP_URL}" />
        </rule>
        <preConditions>
          <preCondition name="3xx Redirect">
            <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="3[0-9][0-9]" />
          </preCondition>
        </preConditions>
      </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
```